# Regex - Various regex for extracting data from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code

```
string s = "add(2,3);";
var matchess = Regex.Matches(s, @"\(\s*(?<num>\d+)\s*(\,\s*(?<num>\d+)\s*)*\)");
                var results = matchess.Cast<Match>()
                    .SelectMany(m => m.Groups["num"].Captures.Cast<Capture>())
                    .Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
```

The above code detects more than 2 inputs of functionname(number,number) and storing the results in an arraylist to be able to be accessed.

Is there any way to change the equation in such a way that it will also accept the following and print the results accordingly?

example 1

```
 string s = "add(2.2,3.3);";
```

result 1

```
results[0] = 2.2
results[1] = 3.3
```

example 2

```
string s = "add(2.4,3.5,6.7);";
```

result 2

```
    results[0] = 2.4
    results[1] = 3.5
    results[2] = 6.7
```

example 3

```
string s = "test("this is a test","just an example");";
```

result 3

```
results[0] = "this is a test"
results[1] = "just an example"
```

example 4

```
 string s = "test("this is a test","just an example","testing");";
```

result 4

```
    results[0] = "this is a test"
    results[1] = "just an example"
    results[2] = "testing"
```

Basically what i need is taking more than 2 inputs of functionname(decimal,decimal) & functionname(string,string) and storing the results in an arraylist to access them.

Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string s = "aa(1.2,3.5)";
    //Or
    string s = "aa(sad,asd)";
    var info = Regex.Split(
        Regex.Matches(s, @"\(.*?\)")
        .Cast<Match>().First().ToString()
        .Replace("(", string.Empty).
        Replace(")", string.Empty), @"[\s,]+");
```

### How it work:

First i get string in `()` area:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"\(.*?\)");
```

Get First Match

```
.Cast<Match>().First().ToString()
```

Remove `(` and `)`

```
.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty)
```

Split Text or number between `,` form result

```
Regex.Split(result, @"[\s,]+");
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Mind explaining a little about how its implemented? I am still learning regex and would like to gain further insight on how u managed to fix my problem. Thanks :)